# Mapping from json a Realm object contained in the db from his ID using Alamofire, ObjectMapper and Realm

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm, objectmapper

I´m using Realm, ObjectMapper and Alamofire to get the data from the server, map it from json and store in the database as RealmObjects.

I have a user class that looks like this:

```
class User:Object, Mappable{

    dynamic var exId = ""
    dynamic var user = ""
    dynamic var password = ""
    dynamic var participant:Participant? = Participant()

    convenience init (exId: String, user: String, password:String, participant:Participant) {
        self.init()
        self.exId = exId
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.participant = participant
    }

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        exId    <- map["id"]
        user  <- map["name"]
        password <- map["password"]
        participant <- map["participantId"]   
    }

}
```

Also I have a participant class that looks like this:

```
class Participant:Object, Mappable{
    dynamic var exId = ""
    @objc dynamic var name = ""

    convenience init(exId:String, name:String) {
        self.init()
        self.exId = exId
        self.name = name
    }

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        exId    <- map["id"]
        name  <- map["name"]
    }

}
```

First I get all the participants, and then I got a json response like this:

```
{"user":{
  "id":"123456EEC",
  "name":"user",
  "pass":"1234",
  "participantId":"123EEF"}
}
```

Which is the best way to get the Participant object, maybe in the init method?

(I know the example is not the best, but it can be applied to a lot of contexts, )

Comment: Do you receive both users and participants in the response of the same network call? If not, are the two calls subsequent? This is an important detail, since it matters a lot whether you have to fetch the existing `Participant` object with the matching `id` from Realm or if you just have to store it in a local variable.

Comment: I receive first the participants, and then when the user makes login, the response with the id of the participant, so my question is where is the best place to get the participant from the id. I guess it is in the init method...